# I'm trying to return data by traversing embedded lists using java 8 streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm battling to return items containing item.baz.fooz == 'snafu' only.  I've anonymized the code and source below.  Your assistance will be appreciated. 
My data source:

```
{
  "data": {
    "searches": [
      {
        "apples": [
          {
            "pears": [
              {
                "sets": [
                  {
                    "items": [
                      {
                        "baz": {
                          "fooz": {
                            "unit": "snafu"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My failing code:

```
List<Item> items =
    response.data.searches.stream()
    .flatMap(
        search -> search.apples.forEach(
           apple -> apple.pears.forEach(
               pear -> pear.sets.forEach(
                   set -> set.items.stream()
                      .filter(item -> item.baz.fooz.unit.equals("snafu"))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList())))));
```

The failures are (among others):

```
Incompatible type. Required List<Foo> but 'flatmap' was inferred to Stream<R>: no instances of type variable R List<Foo>
```

Comment: will need a lot more `flatMap`s... `.flatMap(search -> search.apples.flatMap(apple -> apple.pears.flatMap(.....))).collect(Collectors.toList())`. `flatMap` has to return a `Stream` of something, in your code you are not doing that

Comment: I understand this is just an example, but `searches -> apples -> pears -> sets...`, where you can get `pears` from `apples` just makes no sense

Comment: Substituting the `forEach` with `flatMap` doesn't compile

Comment: that is _your_ problem at this point in time... if you would have provided all the classes, the code that does not compile, people will help; otherwise we can only guess - thus not our problem.

Comment: Please look at the answers and solution below.  I hope that it can help you to contribute better @Eugene

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `forEach`, you need multiple `flatMap`s:

```
List<Item> snoozles =
    response.data
            .searches
            .stream() // Stream<Search>
            .flatMap(search -> search.apples.stream()) // Stream<Apple>
            .flatMap(apple -> apple.pears.stream()) // Stream<Pear>
            .flatMap(pear -> pear.sets.stream()) // Stream<Set>
            .flatMap(set -> set.items.stream() 
                               .filter(item -> item.baz.fooz.unit.equals("snafu"))) // Stream<Item>
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // List<Item>
```

Or (as Holger suggested):

```
List<Item> snoozles =
    response.data
            .searches
            .stream() // Stream<Search>
            .flatMap(search -> search.apples.stream()) // Stream<Apple>
            .flatMap(apple -> apple.pears.stream()) // Stream<Pear>
            .flatMap(pear -> pear.sets.stream()) // Stream<Set>
            .flatMap(set -> set.items.stream()) // Stream<Item>
            .filter(item -> item.baz.fooz.unit.equals("snafu")) // Stream<Item>
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // List<Item>
```

Comment: Thanks @Eran, it seems like the way to go.  I'm still getting the `Incompatible type` error though.  Could you please expand on your last `map` comment?

Comment: @Rick I'll have to know which classes you have. What's the type of `set.items`, and how do you obtain a Foo instance from an "item"?

Comment: you're correct.  I need a `List<Item>` rather.  I've made the edit in the original post.

Comment: @Rick I edited the answer. Of course, without seeing the class declarations I can't be sure.

Comment: The problem is solved.  I neglected to enclose my statements like so:
`.flatMap(apple -> apple.pears.stream())`.  The `(` and `)` where missing to enclose the flatmap call.  So I ended up trying to embed the entire statement.  My IDE started populating `// Stream<Pear>` next to my statements.  Well done, @Eran!

Comment: To clarify: 
my code was looking like this:

....
.flatMap(pear -> pear.sets.stream()
          .flatMap(set -> set.items.stream()
....

and not correctly like this:
.flatMap(pear -> pear.sets.stream())
          .flatMap(set -> set.items.stream())
....

Comment: There is no reason to place the `.filter(…)` within the function passed to `.flatMap`. You can chain it after the last `.flatMap` on the top level.

Comment: @Holger does it matter, or are you suggesting this change for readability reasons?

Comment: Mainly readability. Both variants are formally correct. If the predicate was a capturing lambda, it would be slightly more efficient to place it on the top level, but here, it makes no difference performance-wise. It’s just the readability, i.e. less nesting and having all `flatMap` steps in a uniform shape.

Comment: I agree with @holger. That's what I did. No need to suddenly nest - it breaks the thought flow